# CustomKeyboard hides behind Alertdialog in Android

Tags: android

I have implemented customizeKeyboard on AlertDialog in my Activity. When I click the edittext on Alertdialog, the keyboard opens behind the dialog and is not enable or working. How to make it appear in front?

Here's is my AlertDialog code:

```
private void showSaveDraftDialog() {
    if (!list.isEmpty()) {
        LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(Activity_Sales_Return.this);
        View promptsView = li.inflate(R.layout.save_draft, null);


        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                Activity_Sales_Return.this);

        // set prompts.xml to alertdialog builder
        alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptsView);

        final EditText userInput = (EditText) promptsView
                .findViewById(R.id.et_alert_save_name);
        userInput.requestFocus();

        userInput.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
//                  getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
//                              
WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
                InputMethodManager input = (InputMethodManager)     
getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                input.hideSoftInputFromWindow(userInput.getWindowToken(),0);
//                  if(isCustomKeyboardVisible()){
//                      hideCustomKeyboard();
//                  }else{
        //showCustomKeyboard(v);
        mKeyboardView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mKeyboardView.setEnabled(true);

//                  }
            }
        });
        userInput.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (hasFocus) {
                    key.showCustomNumKeyboard(v);

                    } else {

                        hideCustomKeyboard();
                    }
            }
        });

        // set dialog message
        alertDialogBuilder
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Save",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int id) {
                                if (!userInput.getText().toString().trim()
                                        .equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                                    SaleDraftDatabase saleDraftDatabase = 
new SaleDraftDatabase(
                                            mActivity);
                                    saleDraftDatabase.open();
                                    boolean nameAvailable = 
saleDraftDatabase
                                            .checkDraftNameAvailable(
                                                    userId, userInput
                                                            .getText()
                                                            .toString()
                                                            .trim());
                                    if (nameAvailable) {
                                        boolean saveCheck = 
saleDraftDatabase
                                                .createEntry(list, userId,
                                                        userInput.getText()
                                                                .toString()
                                                                .trim());
                                        saleDraftDatabase.close();
                                        if (saveCheck) {
                                            SalesReturnDatabase saleDatabase 
= new SalesReturnDatabase(
                                                    mActivity);
                                            saleDatabase.open();
                                            saleDatabase

.deleteAllEntriesOfSingleUser(userId);
                                            saleDatabase.close();
                                            list.clear();
                                            barcodeList.clear();
                                            Intent i = new Intent(
                                                    mActivity,

Activity_Sales_Return.class);

i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS
                                                    | 

Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                            startActivity(i);
                                            finish();
                                            Toast.makeText(


Activity_Sales_Return.this,
                                                    userInput.getText()
                                                            .toString()
                                                            .trim()
                                                            + " sale saved 

as draft.",
                                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                                    .show();
                                        } else
                                            Toast.makeText(


Activity_Sales_Return.this,
                                                    "Some error occured",
                                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                                    .show();
                                    } else {
                                        Toast.makeText(
                                                mActivity,
                                                "Name already in use. Choose        

another name.",
                                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    Toast.makeText(
                                            Activity_Sales_Return.this,
                                            "Enter a valid name",
                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            }
                        })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int id) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });
        // create alert dialog
        AlertDialog alertDialog1 = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        alertDialog1.setTitle("Save Draft");
        alertDialog1.setIcon(R.drawable.ttt_logo);
        alertDialog1.show();

    } else {
        Toast.makeText(mActivity, "No Sale started yet !!",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    (1).Remove this line WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);

    (2).Add below line in manifest => in Activity where you have define AlertDialog

    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|adjustPan|stateHidden" 

for example:

            <activity
                android:name="com.example.Login"
                android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|screenSize|locale"
                android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|adjustPan|stateHidden" >
            </activity>
```